# jQuery UI Draggable on droppable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have been trying to put a Draggable element on Droppable element, by jquery ui, and i almost succeded as the code working halfly, if you move a little the elements on the droppable, they are changing their place, and i don't want it to, i want they will stay where they are, but if you drag them outside of the droppable area, they will come back to their natural place.
the code i've done:
HTML:

```
<div class="cart">
<div class="products on">1</div>
<div class="products on">2</div>
</div>

<div class="products">3</div>
<div class="products">4</div>
<div class="new"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(function() {
  $(".products").draggable({
  appendTo: "body",
  revert : function(event, ui) {
  if($(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1] == 'on') {
  $(".new").append($(this)); $(this).removeClass("on"); return !event; 
  }else{
  $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {top : 0,left : 0}; return !event; 
  } },
  start: function(event, ui) { ui.helper.data('dropped', false); },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
  if(!ui.helper.data('dropped')) {
  $("#"+$(this).html()).remove();
  } 
  }
  });

$(".cart").droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var text = ui.draggable.html();
    $(".cart").append('<div id="'+text+'">'+text+'</div>');
    ui.draggable.data('dropped', true);
  }
});

   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yreKf/8/

Comment: Where is their natural place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove destroy draggable on drop event here is working   [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/semir/E9y8Q/)

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var text = ui.draggable.html();
    $(".cart").append('<div id="'+text+'">'+text+'</div>');
    ui.draggable.data('dropped', true);
     $(ui.draggable).draggable({
              revert: "invalid"
          });
  }
```

Comment: This is not what i meant, i want option to drag to droppable and drag out from the droppable.

Comment: is my last answer is okey to you

Comment: almost :) i just need when you drag the draggable outside the droppable, he should go back to his first place, but the divs on the droppable on start, should go to .new when you drag out side the droppable.

Comment: sorry i din't understand what you want exactly :(

Comment: imagine that the red box is a basket, and the yellow ones are the products, and if you drag products to the basket, they will stay there as dropped, if you drag them outside the area, they will come back to their first place. but there are some products that already inside the basket, so they matched as products inside the basket, and if you drag them outside the basket, they will append to .new.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer you are looking for

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ revert: "valid" });
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });

    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
      hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: What i was meant to: imagine that the red box is a basket, and the yellow ones are the products, and if you drag products to the basket, they will stay there as dropped, if you drag them outside the area, they will come back to their first place. but there are some products that already inside the basket, so they matched as products inside the basket, and if you drag them outside the basket, they will append to .new.

Comment: so what is the problem , where do you want the products inside the basket to go when dragged ?!

Comment: When on the basket, they will stay where they are, when they outside, they should leave the basket area and go back.